# Passing a pointer to scanf() produces segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

What is wrong with this code?

```
void input(int *nmbrOfUnits);    

int main() {  
   int *nmbrOfUnits;
   input(nmbrOfUnits);
}

 void input(int *nmbrOfUnits) {
        printf("numnber if units: ");
          scanf(" %d", nmbrOfUnits);

  }
```

edit: the variable is created in main and that should mean if main calls input the variable is not poped from the stack. Why should I allocate it on the heap?
I pass a pointer and use it in scanf. Why do I get a segmentation fault here?

Comment: This isn't java. ;-)

Comment: @2501 - should I take a deep copy :-p

Comment: Try: scanf(" %d", &nmbrOfUnits); The function scanf requires a pointer to the variable(s) in which the data that the user inputs will be written! (This I said is wrong ... I don't look at you code very good!)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini , `nmbrOfUnits` *is* a pointer.

Comment: Ops ... Ok! I don't see that!!! ... Then the problem is that the pointers points nothing!!!!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini; No. Pointer is pointing to a random location.

Comment: Yes ... Is true!!! Is pointing something in the air ;)

Comment: I suggest to use: int nmbrOfUnits; and then input(&nmbrOfUnits); ... If you need to use the pointer you have the reply in the answers you received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
 int *nmbrOfUnits = 0;
```

does not make `nmbrOfUnits` to point to a *valid* memory location to be *read from* or *write into*. To use properly, you need to allocate memory to the pointer first. You can do this two ways.

1. Use dynamic memory allocation [`malloc()/calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Sample code:<sup>`free()`ing part omitted</sup>

```
int *nmbrOfUnits = malloc(sizeof(int));

 int * input(int *nmbrOfUnits) {
        if (!nmbrOfUnits)
        {
              exit(-1);
        }
        printf("numnber if units: ");
          scanf(" %d", nmbrOfUnits);

        return nmbrOfUnits ;
  }
```

2. assign the address of some compile time defined variable.

Sample code:

```
 int variable = 0;
 int *nmbrOfUnits = &variable;
```

and then, pass it to other functions.

Comment: i fixed it. Made i misstake - all the same theres a segmentation fault.

Comment: @java :-) the timestamp is in my favor.

Comment: Disagree with downvote. People should go through the question's edit history.

Comment: @2501; OK, now I see.

Answer (score 5):

The pointer shall point to memory where the value will be written. For example

```
 int *nmbrOfUnits = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
```

or

```
 int x; 
 int *nmbrOfUnits = &x;
```

Another approach is to allow the function itself to allocate the mamory that will be pointed to by the pointer. For example

```
void input( int **nmbrOfUnits ) 
{
    *nmbrOfUnits = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    if ( *nmbrOfUnits != NULL )
    {
        printf( "numnber if units: " );
        scanf( " %d", *nmbrOfUnits );
    }
}

//...

int *nmbrOfUnits;
//...
input( &nmbrOfUnits );
```

Answer (score 3):

`nmbrOfUnits` in not initialized and therefore pointing to a random memory location. Writing to such location may lead to a program crash or it may behave erratically.
 You need to allocate memory first before writing to it.

```
int *nmbrOfUnits = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two variables, both called nmbrOfUnits. This can cause a lot of confusion as to which var you're referring to.

The right way to write it if you want the variable to be global is:

```
int g_nmbrOfUnits;
void input(int *p_nmbrOfUnits) {
    printf("numnber if units: ");  //typos in the original
    scanf("%d", p_nmbrOfUnits);
}
```

and then in another function:

```
input(&g_nmbrOfUnits);
```